# Default values for varchar and int mysql data types

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, default, sqldatatypes

The screenshot show 3 typical definitions of data type: id (autoincrement), a title and a number.

1.- Which are differences between: `none` and `NULL`?
2.- Do I must choose `as defined: ''` for varchar types when I want an empty string?
3.- Do I must put an `as defined: 0` default value for autoincrement int types?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Default none means there is no default value. If a value is not provided on an insert, the query will fail with a "no default value error".

NULL is the actual NULL value meaning if no value is provided on an insert the column will default to NULL (empty). For varchar you can set default to '', but NULL is better.

Autoincrement int types shouldn't have a default value (Default: None) because it will always have a value.

Comment: To further clarify, to use NULL as the default, the column must allow NULL values.

Comment: For integer types NULL in will insert 0 (zero)?

Comment: Marcus, you are correct - "on an insert" I will edit my answer.

Comment: Another interesting thing to note is if you disable ALLOW NULL for a column, and you don't specify a default value (NONE), it will still use the default value for the type (0 for INTEGER, '' for VARCHAR) to replace NULL values.